# MySQL JSON Parsing - Escaped Json-within-Json

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I'm having trouble using the in-built MySQL JSON functions to parse out a value from a JSON string nested inside a JSON string.

Here's a sample:

```
{
  "SucceededAt": "2022-01-18T07:54:50.5548083Z",
  "PerformanceDuration": "1463",
  "Latency": "91",
  "Result": "\"Request Body: {\\\"request\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":[{\\\"value\\\":\\\"1\\\"}],\\\"roles\\\":{\\\"receiver\\\":{\\\"id\\\":[{\\\"value\\\":\\\"1115559991\\\"}]}},\\\"details\\\":{\\\"adjustmentAmount\\\":{\\\"value\\\":7800}}}]}, Response Body:{\\\"response\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":[{\\\"value\\\":\\\"1\\\"}],\\\"parts\\\":{\\\"specification\\\":{\\\"characteristicsValue\\\":[{\\\"characteristicName\\\":\\\"MSISDN\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"9998885556\\\"},{\\\"characteristicName\\\":\\\"ResponseCode\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"1000\\\"},{\\\"characteristicName\\\":\\\"ResponseDescription\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"Operation successfully.\\\"}]}}}]}\""
}
```

I want to get the "request" and response" key/value pairs from within the "Result" key/value.

When I use `SELECT JSON_VALUE(Data, '$.Result') FROM [...]` to extract the value from the "Result" key, it returns the escaped string value (which is again, json-within-json, I think) as follows (with the double-quote characters):

```
"Request Body: {\"request\":[{\"id\":[{\"value\":\"1\"}],\"roles\":{\"receiver\":{\"id\":[{\"value\":\"114787601\"}]}},\"details\":{\"adjustmentAmount\":{\"value\":7800}}}]}, Response Body:{\"response\":[{\"id\":[{\"value\":\"1\"}],\"parts\":{\"specification\":{\"characteristicsValue\":[{\"characteristicName\":\"MSISDN\",\"value\":\"114787601\"},{\"characteristicName\":\"ResponseCode\",\"value\":\"1000\"},{\"characteristicName\":\"ResponseDescription\",\"value\":\"Operation successfully.\"}]}}}]}"
```

This is the step I'm stuck at.

Is there a way to do this with the in-built MySQL JSON functions?

Comment: The value of `result` is not valid JSON, it needs `{}` around the object.

Comment: ahh, you're right. So Basically I need to clean up the results of the JSON_VALUE (add {}, remove the wrapping double quotes, and replace the escape charaters, then parse it as it's own JSON

Comment: Yes, that should work. It won't be pretty, but nothing using JSON is pretty in MySQL.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth - The MySQL version is 8.0.23

Comment: @Barmar json_unquote is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON_UNQUOTE to take the json string returned by JSON_VALUE and turn it into a raw string value.  And then use substring_index to parse out the Request Body: and Response Body:, assuming those are formatted exactly as shown in your example (is there really a space after the colon for the request but not the response??):

```
select
    substring_index(substring_index(json_unquote(json_value(Data, '$.Result')),', Response Body:',1),'Request Body: ',-1) as request,
    substring_index(json_unquote(json_value(Data, '$.Result')),', Response Body:',-1) as response
from foo;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=abf4c9ff342fe1d34445b28c8e6b4a4d)

`substring_index(foo,bar,1)` gets everything before the first bar in foo (or returns the entire string if bar is not found).  `substring_index(foo,bar,-1)` gets everything after the last bar in foo (or returns the entire string if bar is not found).